# How to make an array of all the values from the array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The Object is this -

```
clients = [
  [{
      "label": "MongoDb",
      "value": "5ee71c494be8d0180c1b63d6"
    },
    {
      "label": "Hawlett",
      "value": "5ee71b5e4be8d0180c1b63d2"
    },
    {
      "label": "Coca Cola",
      "value": "5ee7195ef2d5e0175c5da986"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "label": "Tarun infotech",
      "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sahara",
      "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "label": "Tarun infotech",
      "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sahara",
      "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to make the array in the form shown below to get a new array of object ids to perform further task -

```
expected = ["5ee71c494be8d0180c1b63d6","5ee71b5e4be8d0180c1b63d2","5ee7195ef2d5e0175c5da986" ....]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I'm new to Javascript. I hope there's a way to do this in less code.

Comment: Hint: Look into `Array.map`

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh and thanks a lot for editing my question I am really new into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (place all objects into one array) then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the value property into your array.

```js
const clients = [
  [{
      "label": "MongoDb",
      "value": "5ee71c494be8d0180c1b63d6"
    },
    {
      "label": "Hawlett",
      "value": "5ee71b5e4be8d0180c1b63d2"
    },
    {
      "label": "Coca Cola",
      "value": "5ee7195ef2d5e0175c5da986"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "label": "Tarun infotech",
      "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sahara",
      "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "label": "Tarun infotech",
      "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sahara",
      "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
    }
  ]
]

const res = clients
  .flatMap(arr => arr)
  .map(({value}) => value)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Eugen. I am new to this and really overwhelmed by the response the community gave.

Answer (score 2):

Well use `.flat()` and then `.map()`

```js
let clients = [
  [{
      "label": "MongoDb",
      "value": "5ee71c494be8d0180c1b63d6"
    },
    {
      "label": "Hawlett",
      "value": "5ee71b5e4be8d0180c1b63d2"
    },
    {
      "label": "Coca Cola",
      "value": "5ee7195ef2d5e0175c5da986"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "label": "Tarun infotech",
      "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sahara",
      "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
    }
  ],
  [{
      "label": "Tarun infotech",
      "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sahara",
      "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
    }
  ]
]

let result = clients.flat().map(el => el.value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap()` and `map()`:

```js
clients = [
    [
        {
            "label": "MongoDb",
            "value": "5ee71c494be8d0180c1b63d6"
        },
        {
            "label": "Hawlett",
            "value": "5ee71b5e4be8d0180c1b63d2"
        },
        {
            "label": "Coca Cola",
            "value": "5ee7195ef2d5e0175c5da986"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "label": "Tarun infotech",
            "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
        },
        {
            "label": "Sahara",
            "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "label": "Tarun infotech",
            "value": "5ee71cc94be8d0180c1b63db"
        },
        {
            "label": "Sahara",
            "value": "5ee71c884be8d0180c1b63d9"
        }
    ]
];

let values = clients.flatMap(c => c.map(a => a.value));
console.log(values);
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul Bhobe